# Connection String for Windows mobile device from Windows 8

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, connection

here Win 8 has mssql database, im trying to connect this via Motorola mobile device ( MK500 ). 
 im using this
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ConnectionString>Data Source=server-desktop;User ID=sa;Password=Test123;Initial Catalog=shopriteDB;</ConnectionString>
</ConSettings>`

but its keep giving me error.

this is is my details ( here i change name bit)

```
Server name    : server-desktop     User name : sa
Database name  : shopriteDB         Password  : Test123

Instance Name : PCAMERICA


Error message i get is
" Specifid SQL Server not found : Server-desktop\PCAMERICA
Line no : 0
Source : .NET SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure : ConnectionOpen(Connect()).
```

Answer (score 0):

First you check that your `sqlserver services` are running or not..

To check `window + run` -> type `SERVICES.MSC` enter -> will open services window.

On that find `Sqlserver (your version) and SQL server browser services` , is that in running mode. if not then right click and `start` both.

Check now.

If the services are started, then just open SSMS and in login select `Browse` option on server dropdown. This will tell you the list of Sqlserver in your network including yours.

Still if you can not find, check this link for Sql configuration

http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944390

http://www.teratrax.com/specified-sql-server-not-found/